# How to Validate Email address using OSB Xquey

Tags: validation, email, xquery, osb

I would like to validate email address inside OSB Xquery.

Currently I am validating like this:

```
if (not((fn:matches(fn:lower-case($reporter/ns4:emailAddress),'^[a-z0-9+]+([\._-][a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9]+){0,4}\.[a-z0-9]{1,4}$')))
```

I would like to add more validation over here like Email id will come like in below format. Example email address:

```
abcdefg.hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&'*/=?^_+-`{|}~0123456789@acme-inc.com
```

Before the @ sign `` abcdefg.hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&'*/=?^_+-`{|}~0123456789 ``. When I am trying to add this I am getting an error for `&`. How do I add this token?

Comment: how to use '  in the OSB xquery on the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Testing with:

```
let $email := "abcdefg.hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&amp;'*/=?^_+-`{|}~0123456789@acme-inc.com"
return
    fn:matches(fn:lower-case($email),'^[a-z0-9+]+([._-][a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9_-]+(.[a-z0-9]+){0,4}.[a-z0-9]{1,4}$')
```

This returns 'false' like you want, right? So, what is the issue?

Note: I escaped the &, since that is a special character in XQuery.

HTH!

Comment: Is there any way i can use &, in the email validation field?

Comment: @user3310812 What do you mean by 'email validation field'? In XQuery &amp; represents &, so I think this is what you are looking for..